# Updating 2 mongoose schemas in an api call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Currently I'm trying to update Two different User Schema's in an api call.

The first schema is logged in user schema, we give it a name = Tom
The second schema is other users who signup for the app, we give it a name = John

The schema code

schema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');



var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    followersCount: Number,
    followingCount: Number

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The api name is '/follow/:user_id', what I want to achieve is . Whenever user Tom follows other user's like John, Tom's **following** field will be updated as well as John's **follower** field.

My current attempt (req.decoded.id is the logged in user)

api.js

```
// The first way

apiRouter.post('/follow/:user_id', function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {   

        _id: req.decoded.id, 
        following: { $ne: req.params.user_id }
    }, 

    { 
        $push: { following: req.params.user_id},
        $inc: { followingCount: 1}

    },
    function(err, currentUser) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(currentUser);

    });
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {

        _id: req.params.user_id,
        followers: { $ne: req.decoded.id } 

    },

    {
        $push: { followers: req.decoded.id },
        $inc: { followersCount: 1}

    }, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            message: "Successfully followed"
        });
    }
    )
});


//Second way

apiRouter.post('/follow/:user_id', function(req, res) {

    // find a current user that has logged in
        User.update(
            {   
                _id: req.decoded.id, 
                following: { $ne: req.params.user_id } 
            }, 

            { 
                $push: { following: req.params.user_id},
                $inc: { followingCount: 1}

            },
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                }

                User.update(
                    {
                        _id: req.params.user_id,
                        followers: { $ne: req.decoded.id }
                    },

                    {   
                        $push: { followers: req.decoded.id },
                        $inc: { followersCount: 1}

                    }

                ), function(err) {
                    if(err) return res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: "Successfully Followed!" });
                }

        });
});
```

Both have problems,

The first way: The problem is, 'Can't set headers that already sent', because of the two separate mongoose query in one api call, it response twice that's why I get that error.

The second way: The problem is, the **following** field of logged in user(Tom) gets updated while the other user's **followers** field (John) return null. I console log both value and as well test it with POSTMAN chrome app.

Lend me your thoughts fellas!

Comment: What do you mean by "the other user's followers field (John) return null"?

Comment: "Can't set headers that already sent" has nothing to do with mongoose or your queries. It has to do with calling `res.send()` or `res.json()` more than once. The only way that could happen in the first example is if the top `findOneAndUpdate` had an error.

Answer (score 1):

The first route you took seems to be fine.

However, as @cdbajorin mentioned, the error "can't send headers that already sent" has nothing to do with mongoose but the fact that you're trying to set the header after sending a response to the client already. ([see this lovely answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent))

My suggestion would be to make sure that both database calls are successful before you send a response.

You may also want to look into a [two phase commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) in this situation, as MongoDB does not support traditional DB transactions and you're updating two documents, one at a time. If for some reason either database call fails, a procedure to recover to a stable state should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The first way can be improved in two ways. One is updating followers field inside the callback of updating following field. The other way is using async-waterfall. I suggest to go with async-waterfall(npm async-waterfall).

Comment: Can you show me some example so i can accept your answer and give you the bounty

Comment: Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705067/using-async-waterfall-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

The second way it is correct (could be improved running both of them in parallel) I guess the problem is in another place. I don't know which framework you are using but i guess the field `_id` is from mongoDB and is an `ObjectId` and looks like that the decoded.id can be an objectId while the one that comes from the request is of course just a string. So I guess it is empty because it does not find any user with that string.

Try do make it an objectId out of that string ( reffering to `req.params.user_id` in the second query)